# Application is freeze when "this.props.navigation.navigate"

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo 34 and I am tried with 32,33 and 31.

It works when I run it with Expo client on Ios Simulator but
In the "this.props.navigation.navigate" commands, the program freezes and the cpu rises.
I'm not getting a mistake either.
I have the same problem with Android tests.
Expo client version 2.12.1

I tried it separately on Windows and Apple operating systems to solve this problem, but the problem still persisted.

Not: In the meantime, the application I am talking about is now online.
I mean, he was definitely working before, but I can't even test him now.

Comment: Can you show me your package.json and the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install that in your project.

```
npm install react-navigation --save
```

Also you need to pass in the view name. For example:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewName');
```

Comment: Hi @jazzmasterkc I tried but it not work.  When I tested even older versions of the React native navigation package, I got the same result.